# WeatherData function problem: "NonMetricValue" returns undated list of values

Tags: data, curated-data

In the WL example below, `WeatherData[]` returns an undated list of values when I add the annotation "NonMetricValue."

```
WeatherData["New York City", "MeanTemperature", {{2013,12,1},{2013,12,12},"Day"}]
```

> {{{2013,12,1},5.5},{{2013,12,2},6.06},{{2013,12,3},4.94},{{2013,12,4},6.5},
>        {{2013,12,5},9.17},{{2013,12,6},11.56},{{2013,12,7},3.22},{{2013,12,8},0.11},
>        {{2013,12,9},0.22},{{2013,12,10},2.22},{{2013,12,11},-0.72},
>        {{2013,12,12},-1.22}}

```
WeatherData["New York City", "MeanTemperature", 
     {{2013,12,1},{2013,12,12},"Day"}, "NonMetricValue"]
```

> {41.9,42.91,40.89,43.7,48.51,52.81,37.8,32.2,32.4,36.,30.7,29.8}

This seems like a bug, since a proper effect would change only the values.  Aside from that, is this a syntax problem (am I doing it wrong)? I would like to be able to get a date list of temperature in Fahrenheit directly from `WeatherData[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the form "DateNonMetricValue". E.g.

```
WeatherData["New York City", "MeanTemperature", {{2013, 12, 
   1}, {2013, 12, 12}, "Day"}, "DateNonMetricValue"]
```

The result is then:

> {{{2013, 12, 1}, 41.9}, {{2013, 12, 2}, 42.91}, {{2013, 12, 3},
>   40.89}, {{2013, 12, 4}, 43.7}, {{2013, 12, 5}, 48.51}, {{2013, 12, 6}, 52.81}, {{2013, 12, 7}, 37.8}, {{2013, 12, 8}, 32.2}, {{2013, 12, 9}, 32.4}, {{2013, 12, 10}, 36.}, {{2013, 12, 11}, 30.7}, {{2013, 12, 12}, 29.8}}

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see this annotation in the documentation. Is it just me, or are these curated data annotations/options poorly documented?